# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MW01.Web.Model.Countries]' to type 'MW01.Web.Model.Country'.'

Tags: c#, json, api, umbraco, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize an object from API but I keep getting either cast error.

Here is my Country class:

```
public class Country
    {
        public List<Countries> country { get; set; }
    }

    public class Countries
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("alpha3code")]
        public string Alpha3Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("capital")]
        public string Capital { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("region")]
        public string Region { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("subregion")]
        public string SubRegion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("borders")]
        public string[] Borders { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my controller method:

```
private void CreateCountries(Country model)
        {
            IContentService cs = Services.ContentService;

            var parentNode = cs.GetById(1097);
            var parentUdi = new GuidUdi(parentNode.ContentType.ToString(), parentNode.Key);

            Country listofQuery = WikiData.GetCountries();
            List<Countries> queryList = new List<Countries>();

            foreach (Countries countries in listofQuery.country)
            {
                queryList.Add(countries);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
```

points to my WikiData class:

```
public static Country GetCountries()
        {
            string feed = "https://ajayakv-rest-countries-v1.p.rapidapi.com/rest/v1/all/?rapidapi-key=be78b7ef9cmshba4472195aeedbep1bf589jsncac9cc382cca";

            
            return serialized_CountryData<Country>(feed);
            
        }
```

And on to:

```
public static T serialized_CountryData<T>(string url) where T : new()
        {
            using (var w = new WebClient())
            {
                w.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

                var json_data = string.Empty;

                try
                {
                    json_data = w.DownloadString(url);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
                
                //return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json_data) : new T();

                IEnumerable<Countries> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Countries>>(json_data);

                return (T)result;
            }
        }
```

But after this I get the error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MW01.Web.Model.Countries]' to type 'MW01.Web.Model.Country'."

I've tried many different approaches to this issue and they all result in some sort of cast error or object definition error. Any idea how to solve this?

**EDIT:**

When attempting to do this (which feels like it should work):

```
public static Country GetCountries()
        {
            string feed = "https://ajayakv-rest-countries-v1.p.rapidapi.com/rest/v1/all/?rapidapi-key=be78b7ef9cmshba4472195aeedbep1bf589jsncac9cc382cca";

            var testing = serialized_CountryData<Country>(feed);
            return testing;
        }
```

and

```
public static T serialized_CountryData<T>(string url) where T : new()
        {
            using (var w = new WebClient())
            {
                w.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

                var json_data = "";

                try
                {
                   json_data = w.DownloadString(url);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }

                
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json_data);

                return result;
            }
        }
```

This builds just fine but when loading the website I get:

"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'MW01.Web.Model.Country' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array."

And I'm not sure how to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

In controller

Replace

```
return serialized_CountryData<Country>(feed);
```

with

```
return serialized_CountryData<IEnumerable<Country>>(json_data);
```

**Or replace**

```
return serialized_CountryData<Country>(feed);
```

with

```
return serialized_CountryData<Country>(json_data);
```

Comment: I had an error in the original posting, but I edited it now (was trying stuff out and forgot to change it back). So as it is now making the method IEnumerable would give cast error when returning serialized_CountryData<Country>(feed);

Answer (score 0):

### Fix 1:

You are returning an IEnumerable in a function that wants a Countries object. See comment I added to your code:

```
// this function returns a list
public static T serialized_CountryData<T>(string url) where T : new()
        {
            using (var w = new WebClient())
            {
                w.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

                var json_data = string.Empty;

                try
                {
                    json_data = w.DownloadString(url);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
                
                //return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json_data) : new T();

                IEnumerable<Countries> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Countries>>(json_data);

                return (T)result;
            }
        }
```

```
// but this function definition states it returns a single Country
public static Country GetCountries()
        {
            string feed = "https://ajayakv-rest-countries-v1.p.rapidapi.com/rest/v1/all/?rapidapi-key=be78b7ef9cmshba4472195aeedbep1bf589jsncac9cc382cca";

            using (var w = new WebClient())
            {
                w.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

                var json_data = string.Empty;

                try
                {
                    json_data = w.DownloadString(feed);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }

                // but here it returns the output of the above mentioned funciton -> and this is a list
                return serialized_CountryData<Country>(feed);
            }
        }

// therefore you have to change the funciton definition to
public static IEnumerable<Country> GetCountries(){
  // content
}
```

### Fix 2:

and as @Useme mentioned you also have to replace

```
return serialized_CountryData<Country>(feed);
```

with

```
return serialized_CountryData<Country>(json_data);
```

### Fix 3:

Please do me the favor and rename Countries to Country and vice versa. Then you won't get confused. Then it is clear when you pass multiple and when you pass single entries. For example:

```
public List<Country> GetCountries(){}
public Country GetCountry(){}
```

or with an additional object named Countries it would be:

```
public Countries GetCountries(){}
public Country GetCountry(){}
```

Comment: Thanks will give this a try, I just realized I posted my public static Country GetCountries() with the using webclient due to me trying some stuff, but in that method it should only be the feed and the return serialized_CountryData<Country>(feed).

Comment: Fixed edit now so its representative of how its supposed to be